# Cannot iterate over object created with key and value as a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table whose values I read and want to create an object which I can later convert to a string using JSON.stringify.

This is my code to create the object

```
  function dummy(){
    let finalDict = {};
    $(function() {
        $("#tableCountry tr").each(function(){
            
                let key = $(this).children().eq(0).text();
                console.log(key);
                let val = [
                    $(this).children().eq(1).text(), 
                    $(this).children().eq(2).text(), 
                    $(this).children().eq(3).text(),
                    $(this).children().eq(4).text()
                ];
                console.log(key, val);
                finalDict[key] = val;
           
        });
    });
    for (const i in finalDict){
        console.log(i);
    }

    return finalDict;
```

It prints nothing when I run the for loop. Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() { ... });
```

is just jQuery short-hand for

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

So, what you essentially have, is:

```
let finalDict = {};
$(document).ready(function() {
    finalDict['key'] = 'value';
});
console.log(finalDict);
```

So, as you might expect, `finalDict` will not be populated when the `console.log` happens, as you haven't given time for the `ready` event to trigger, and the `console.log` is outside of it.  The easy fix would be to move that block to the bottom of the `$(function() {` block

```
function dummy(){
  let finalDict = {};
  $(function() {
    $("#tableCountry tr").each(function(){
        
            let key = $(this).children().eq(0).text();
            console.log(key);
            let val = [
                $(this).children().eq(1).text(), 
                $(this).children().eq(2).text(), 
                $(this).children().eq(3).text(),
                $(this).children().eq(4).text()
            ];
            console.log(key, val);
            finalDict[key] = val;
       
    });
    for (const i in finalDict){
        console.log(i);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi! I am new to jQuery so I don't get your solution. Would you pls write out the fix? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution. It helps a lot. Now, my next thing is how should I return the populated finalDict from the dummy() function?

Answer (score 0):

$(function() {} ) has similar meaning of $(document).ready(). You may read about it from [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). For your usecase it is totally optional to use it so try for now to skip it or put your complete code inside one of them. I've refined your code below as

```
    function dummy() {
    let finalDict = [];
    $("#tableCountry tr").each(function () {
      let key = $(this).children().eq(0).text();
      console.log(key);
      let val = [
        $(this).children().eq(1).text(),
        $(this).children().eq(2).text(),
        $(this).children().eq(3).text(),
        $(this).children().eq(4).text(),
      ];
      console.log(key, val);
      finalDict[key] = { key: val };

      for (const i in finalDict) {
        console.log(i);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Excellent answer of the function method .

In each HTML/JSP/JS file that using JQuery, we always need to wait the whole page to be loaded successfull. I made a simple HTML to visualize this example.

test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple HTML Document</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("h1").css("color", "#0088ff");
            dummy();
        });
        
        function dummy(){
          let finalDict = {};
          $(function() {
            $("#tableCountry tr").each(function(){
                
                    let key = $(this).children().eq(0).text();
                    console.log(key);
                    let val = [
                        $(this).children().eq(1).text(), 
                        $(this).children().eq(2).text(), 
                        $(this).children().eq(3).text(),
                        $(this).children().eq(4).text()
                    ];
                    console.log(key, val);
                    finalDict[key] = val;
               
            });
            for (const i in finalDict){
                console.log(i);
            }
          });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <div>
        <table id="tableCountry">
            <tr><td>a</td></tr>
            <tr><td>b</td></tr>
            <tr><td>c</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Outcome:
[outputOfColsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TuDY.png)